# Discrepancy in Results with Self-Adjoint Operator on a Special Hilbert Space in 2D Geometric Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I am exploring the behavior of multivectors in 2D geometric algebra, specifically examining the product $\mathbf{u}^\ddagger \mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u}=a+xe_1+ye_2+be_{12}$ and its Clifford conjugate $\mathbf{u}^\ddagger=a-xe_1-ye_2-be_{12}$.

I defined an operator $g\mathbf{u}= I \mathbf{u} I^{-1}$, with $I=e_{12}$, leading to:

$$ I (a+xe_1+ye_2+be_{12})I^{-1}=a-xe_1-ye_2+be_{12} $$

I presumed $g$ is self-adjoint, since $g^\ddagger \mathbf{u} = (-I)\mathbf{u} (-I)^{-1} = I \mathbf{u}I^{-1}$.

However, I'm encountering different results based on the order of operation:

1. When applying $g$ to the right-most term of $\mathbf{u}^\ddagger (g\mathbf{u})$:

   $$ \mathbf{u}^\ddagger (g\mathbf{u}) = (a-xe_1-ye_2-be_{12})(a-xe_1-ye_2+be_{12}) $$
2. When applying $g$ immediately to the left-most term $\mathbf{u}$:

   $$ (g\mathbf{u})^\ddagger \mathbf{u} = (a+xe_1+ye_2-be_{12})(a+xe_1+ye_2+be_{12}) $$

These results aren't aligning as I expected. I am puzzled by this discrepancy. Since $(g\mathbf{u})^\ddagger= \mathbf{u}^\ddagger g^\ddagger$ and $g^\ddagger=g$, I anticipated that all expressions should yield the same result : $(g\mathbf{u})^\ddagger \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}^\ddagger g \mathbf{u}$ . Am I misunderstanding something in my approach, or is there a subtlety in the application of the self-adjoint operator in this context? Any insights or corrections to my method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scalar product corresponding to the quadratic form $\|u\|^2 = u^{\ddagger}u$ is $(u, v) = \mathrm{re}(u^{\ddagger}v)$, where $\mathrm{re}(a + xe_1 + ye_2 + be_{12}) = a$. Self-adjointness of $g$ means $(u, gv) = (gu, v)$, that is, $\mathrm{re}(u^{\ddagger}(gv)) = \mathrm{re}((gu)^{\ddagger}v)$, not $u^{\ddagger}(gu) = (gu)^{\ddagger}u$

Comment: Is your claim that g is not self-adjoint with respect to the inner product? If so, that is also what I was leaning towards.

Comment: No, $g$ is self-adjoint. But self-adjoint does not mean $u^{\ddagger}(gu) = (gu)^{\ddagger}u$. I edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Ah. My understanding was that in quantum mechanics $< O \psi | \phi> = <\psi | O \phi>$ for all $\psi$ and $\phi$ implies $O^\dagger=O$, and vice-versa. Is your claim that this relation does not extant to the present construction?

Comment: Yes, this is true. And your $g$ does satisfy both of these conditions.

Comment: When we write $(gu)^{\dagger}\cdot v = u^{\dagger}g^{\dagger} \cdot v = u^{\dagger}g \cdot v = u^{\dagger}\cdot gv$, the product in the middle means scalar product, not Clifford product.

Comment: Is it the case $(g\mathbf{u})^\ddagger = \mathbf{u}^\ddagger g^\ddagger$ is false?

Comment: First of all, you need to define what does the product $u^{\ddagger}g^{\dagger}$ mean when $g^{\dagger}$ is on the right.

Comment: Okay, it seems the actual relation for self-adjoint is $(\mathbf{O} \mathbf{u})^\ddagger \mathbf{v} =  \mathbf{u}^\ddagger \mathbf{O}^\ddagger \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^\ddagger \mathbf{O} \mathbf{v}$. Any $\mathbf{O}$ that satisfy this "triple-relation" should be self adjoint. Here I assume $\mathbf{O}$ is also a multivector. This is because $(\mathbf{O} \mathbf{u})^\ddagger  \neq \mathbf{u}^\ddagger \mathbf{O}^\ddagger$. Could this be correct? Obviously if $\mathbf{O}$ is merely a real number, then this is satisfied.

Comment: What do you mean by multivector? In the equations you write $u, v$ are vectors, $u^{\ddagger}$, and $(Ou)^{\ddagger}$ are covectors, and $O$ and $O^{\ddagger}$ are linear maps. And the whole product that is being transformed is a scalar.

Comment: $u=a+xe_1+ye_2+be_{12}$, it contains a scalar, a vector and a pseudoscalar. I am using geometric algebra. $u^\ddagger$ is the Clifford conjugate. $u^\ddagger u = a^2-x^2-y^2+b^2$ which is a scalar.

Comment: Then $g$ in the question is not a multivector. There is no element $\mathbf{g}$ in the clifford algebra such that $\mathbf{g}\mathbf{u} = I\mathbf{u}I^{-1}$.
The $g$ is a linear map, and the equation $(gu)^{\ddagger}v = u^{\ddagger}g^{\ddagger}v$ is not true. What is true for every linear map $g$ is $(gu)\cdot v = u \cdot g^{\ddagger}v$ where $\cdot$ is the scalar product.

Comment: Yes, g isn't a multivector in the original problem. I was trying to figure out where my mistake was. I think it was assuming that $(gu)^\ddagger=u^\ddagger g^\dagger$. This line is false. So self adjoint is still $(Ou)^\ddagger v = u^\ddagger O v$, but I can't use $(Ou)^\ddagger v=u^\ddagger O^\ddagger v$. And g is not self-adjoint then.

Comment: Yes, the mistake is in $(gu)^{\ddagger} = u^{\ddagger} g^\dagger$. But $g$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion that g is self-adjoint if $(gu)^\ddagger v \neq u^\ddagger g v $? Here, I mean self adjoint with respect to $u^\ddagger u$, not with respect to the complex norm.

Comment: Because self-adjointness is not $(gu)^{\ddagger}v = u^{\ddagger}gv$ with Clifford products. Self-adjointness is $(gu, v) = (u, gv)$, with the scalar product.

Comment: I think you are mixing the notation. In the Clifford algebra we have the conjugation $u^{\ddagger}$ and the quadratic norm $u^{\ddagger}u$ is always a scalar, but $u^{\ddagger}v$ is in general not a scalar.
In the usual vector spaces we have adjoint $u^{\dagger}$ which is a covector, not a vector, and $(u, v) = u^\dagger v$ is always a scalar. So we write $(gu, v) = (u, gv)$ as $(gu)^\dagger v = u^\dagger (gv)$, but it is important that the product is the scalar product, not some other product like from Clifford algebra

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. g is actually not self-adjoint with respect to $u^\ddagger u$ (which is the inner product I am working with). It is in fact a similarity transformation that maps $u^\ddagger$ to $u^T$. The fact that $g^\ddagger=g$ is merely a coincidence. It is also the case that $(gu)^\ddagger= u^\ddagger g^\dagger$ and this holds for any two multivectors as well as g. I have verified it. One can show self-adjointness with $(O u)^\ddagger v = u^\ddagger O v$ implies that $O^\ddagger = O$. However, g is not an operator Ou, but a similarity transformation $gu=IuI^{-1}$.

Comment: In fact g is a unitary operator for the inner product $<g u, g u>= <u, u>$, hence a valid change of basis operator.